# show third level of ul li on hover of second level of ul li

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the drop down menu style..

when I mouse hover the third level, the second level font color is changed to its color..

I want to make it keep white (as hover) when third level is hover..

How can I make it?

My style:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
<style>
ul#menu
{
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline;
    min-height: 45px;
    overflow: auto;
}
 
    ul#menu li
    {
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 20px;
        background-color: #ff6a00;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #181818;
        border-top: 2px solid #303030;
        min-width: 160px;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        min-height: 45px;
    }
 
        ul#menu li:hover
        {
            background-color: #808080;
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1c1c1c', endColorstr='#1b1b1b');
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1c1c1c', endColorstr='#1b1b1b')";
            border-bottom: 2px solid #222222;
            border-top: 2px solid #1B1B1B;
        }
 
        ul#menu li a
        {
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 0px;
            border-left: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            color: white;
            display: block;
            font-family: 'Lucida Console';
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 45px;
            padding: 0 10px;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-align: left;
        }
 
            ul#menu li a:hover
            {
                border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
                border-left: 3px solid #C4302B;
                color: #C4302B;
            }
 
        ul#menu li:hover
        {
            background-color: #DA251D;
        }
 
        ul#menu li ul
        {
            display: none;
        }
 
        ul#menu li:hover ul
        {
            display: block;
        }
 
        ul#menu li ul li
        {
            float: none;
        }
 

#menu .submenu li:hover a
{
    border-left: 3px solid #454545;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
}
 
#menu > li:hover .submenu, .menu > li:focus .submenu
{
    max-height: 2000px;
    z-index: 10;
}
 
    #menu > li:hover .submenu li, .menu > li:focus .submenu li
    {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        -moz-transform: none;
        -ms-transform: none;
        -o-transform: none;
        transform: none;
    }
 
</style>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
 
<body>
  <div class="ThirdMenu">
    <ul id="menu" class="menu">
      <li>sangeet
        <ul class="submenu" id="submenu"
          <li>sdfsadf
            <ul class="thirdmenu" id="thirdmenu"><li>sdfsd</li></ul>
          </li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tell me simple way to display third menu hover on main category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i got you right:

HTML:

```
<div class="menu_wrap">
    <ul class="newlevel level0">
        <li><a href="#">level0, link 1</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">level0, link 2</a>
            <ul class="newlevel level1">
                <li><a href="#">level1, link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">level1, link 2</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">level1, link 3</a>
                    <ul class="newlevel level2">
                        <li><a href="#">level2, link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">level2, link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">level2, link 3</a></li>
                    </ul>    
                </li>
            </ul>    
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">level0, link 3</a></li>    
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu_wrap
{
    width: 300px;
}

ul
{
    padding: 0;
}

li
{
    list-style: none;    
}

a
{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #ff6a00;
    color: #000;
    border-top: 1px solid;
}

a:hover, .current > a
{
    background: #DA251D;
}

.level1 a
{
    padding-left: 40px;    
}

.level2 a
{
    padding-left: 80px;    
}

.level0 ul
{
    display: none;
}

.newlevel li:hover > ul
{
    display: block;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.newlevel li').hover(function(){
        if ($(this).children('ul').length > 0){
            $(this).addClass('current');  
        }
    },function(){
            $(this).removeClass('current');    
    });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/esf90kz5/3/

Comment: Really really thank u bro........................its working... and before 6day to today i try to find out it but i cant get my answare but u did it